# Seeing own question and answer bans

Tags: feature-request

Unfortunately, I've received a ban on Drupal Answers, but I cannot remember which ban is in effect. Of course, I could ask and/or answer a question, and find out quickly enough, but I think a page listing this would be helpful.

Comment: Any ban would have been automatic, and since we don't have automatic question-banning here it must be a ban on answers. Did you not receive any sort of notification at all?

Comment: Sorry, this feature request is for Drupal Answers, not Meta.  I've reworded my question to specify this.  Yes, I received a notice when I tried to post, I'm just suggesting a way to view this under a user's profile.

Comment: Yep I got that, I was referring to your DA account :) I don't disagree with your request, mods can see this info I don't see the harm in letting individual users see it too

Comment: As long as it stays between a-banned user and mods, I agree. Displaying automatic bans to general public seems at least unneeded.